# Extract the sequence matrix elements?

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix

I have a matrix as shown in below:

```
A=[2 4;1 3;8 6;5 1;4 9]
```

now i need to extract the matrix A into 2 parts:

```
newpoint=[2 4];
rest=[1 3;8 6;5 1;4 9];
```

then apply loop again to extract the second column as new point :

```
newpoint=[1 3];
rest=[2 4;8 6;5 1;4 9];
```

Applying loop again to take third column number as new point :

```
newpoint=[8 6];
rest=[2 4;1 3;5 1;4 9];
```

Take the number in row sequence until the last row . Can someone be kind enough to help.Thanks~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from HebeleHododo's answer, if you have big matrices maybe you can try this:

```ml
A = [2 4; 1 3; 8 6; 5 1; 4 9];

B = zeros(size(A,1)-1,size(A,2));

for idx = 1:size(A, 1)
    newpoint = A(idx, :);
    B(1:idx-1,:) = A(1:idx-1,:);
    B(idx:end,:) = A(idx+1:end,:);
    % do stuff
end
```

It doesn't get rid of the `for` loop, but the temporary B matrix is pre-allocated and the copy between A and B is clear, which makes it quicker.

For `A = rand(100000,2);` HebeleHododo's method takes ~123 seconds in my computer
and the one above takes ~85 seconds.

**Edit:** *Just for reference, the timing is done using `Intel Core i5-3450 CPU @ 3.10GHz` and `Matlab R2011b`*

Answer (score 2):

You said you want to extract columns, but gave examples with rows. I am going ahead and assuming you meant rows.

You can do it with a for loop.

```
A = [2 4; 1 3; 8 6; 5 1; 4 9];

for idx = 1:size(A, 1)
    newpoint = A(idx, :);
    rest = A; % Copy A to rest
    rest(idx, :) = []; % Remove newpoint line
    % do stuff
end
```

---

Results of first two iterations:

```
newpoint =

     2     4

rest =

     1     3
     8     6
     5     1
     4     9

newpoint =

     1     3

rest =

     2     4
     8     6
     5     1
     4     9
```

This is not a good method if your `A` matrix is big.

**Edit:** In fact, do not use this method. George Aprilis timed it and found 123 seconds for a 100000x2 matrix. I guess my computer is much slower. It took 216 seconds. I repeat, do not use this.